# Read .CSV file by using operator >>

Tags: c++, class, csv

I have a class to read CSV file

```
class CSVStudentReader {
    ifstream inStream;
public:
    CSVStudentReader(string fileName): inStream(fileName.c_str()) {}
    Student* readNextStudent() {
        if (inStream.good())
        {
            string name;
            float math;
            float english;
            inStream >> name >> math >> english;
            return new Student(name, math, english);//Student is another class
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    ~CSVStudentReader()
    {
        inStream.close();
    }
};
```

I must use this class to read CSV file and haven't to change it. But CSV file seperate by "," so program err at "inStream >> name >> math >> english;". How to use this class?

Comment: There are a multitude of "reading CSV in C++" type questions on this forum. See [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+istream+csv) for some examples.

Comment: All of them use getline to read CSV :( But this class use >>

Comment: Did my code work for you??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do this. One is to create a class that classifies a comma as whitespace. Using the example from cppreference:

```
#include <locale>
#include <vector>

class csv_whitespace
    : public std::ctype<char>
{
public:
    static const mask* make_table()
    {
        static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size);
        v[','] |=  space;
        v[' '] &= ~space;
        return &v[0];
    }

    csv_whitespace(std::size_t refs = 0) : ctype(make_table(), false, refs) { }
};

#include <memory>

class csv_student_reader
{
private:
    std::ifstream file;
public:
    csv_student_reader(std::string path) :
        file{path}
    {
        file.imbue(std::locale(file.getloc(), new csv_whitespace));
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Student> read_next_student()
    {
        std::string name;
        float math;
        float english;

        if (file >> name >> math >> english)
        {
            return new Student{name, math, english};
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

Compile with:

> `g++-4.8 -std=c++11  -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp  && ./a.out`

Comment: Tricky, tricky. Won't handle quoted strings, but otherwise pretty slick.